# How to loop through a div and add a class using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've found how to find a regular expression in a div, and even on how to add a class using one, but I haven't been able to find an example where I can loop the process. I tried `indexOf()` and couldn't get that to work for me. I'm not sure that's even what I need. What I'd like to do, is change text in my label `#variant_label` that is between two square brackets [ ], red. I can do that, but it only works on the first label - it doesn't work on the second.

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="id" value="value" id="radio_variant-id" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio_variant-id" id="variant_label">5 Packs of 4 (20 Count) [Save 10%]</label>
<p class="variant_price">PRICE <span>SKU</span></p>

<input type="radio" name="id" value="value" id="radio_variant-id" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio_variant-id" id="variant_label">10 Packs of 4 (40 Count) [Save 15%]</label>
<p class="variant_price">PRICE <span>SKU</span></p>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.highlight {color: #F00}
```

Here's the JavaScript with my regex that makes "[Save 10%]" red, but doesn't work on "[Save 15%]":

```
var o = document.getElementById("variant_label");
o.innerHTML = o.innerHTML.replace(/(?:^|[^!])(\[[^[\]]*])/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
```

Here is a fiddle of what I have: https://jsfiddle.net/dr4vp2sq/1/

I found this fiddle that accomplishes what I want to do, but I need to narrow it down to *just* the text within my `#variant_label` and I'm having a hard time figuring out how. http://jsfiddle.net/cz6owdxx/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use class** `class="variant_label"` instead of duplicate ID:

```js
function replacer(el) {
 el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.replace(/(?:^|[^!])(\[[^[\]]*])/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
}

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".variant_label"), replacer);
```

```css
.highlight{color:red;}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="id" value="value" id="radio_variant-id1" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio_variant-id1" class="variant_label">5 Packs of 4 (20 Count) [Save 10%]</label>
<p class="variant_price">PRICE <span>SKU</span></p>

<input type="radio" name="id" value="value" id="radio_variant-id2" checked="checked" />
<label for="radio_variant-id2" class="variant_label">10 Packs of 4 (40 Count) [Save 15%]</label>
<p class="variant_price">PRICE <span>SKU</span></p>
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you times a billion!

Comment: @amandathewebdev you're very welcome! Just, notice that my example might not be suitable for older IE8 and below since the use of JS `forEach`. if you're OK with that fine, otherwise use a `for` loop (like in Rion's example). Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I will consider that and switch to a `for` if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You currently have multiple elements with the same [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) attribute, which constitutes invalid markup as they are unique by definition :

> The id global attribute defines a unique identifier (ID) **which must be
>   unique in the whole document**. Its purpose is to identify the element
>   when linking (using a fragment identifier), scripting, or styling
>   (with CSS).

**Consider Using Classes Instead**

Since `id` based targeting is going to be out of the question for multiple elements (this includes your `<input>` elements and anything else), you might consider using `class` attributes instead :

```
<!-- Other code omitted for brevity -->
<label for="radio_variant-id" class="variant_label">5 Packs of 4 (20 Count) [Save 10%]</label>
<label for="radio_variant-id" class="variant_label">10 Packs of 4 (40 Count) [Save 15%]</label>
```

and then use [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) to grab your labels and then apply your expression to them, which should work as expected :

```
// Get your labels
var labels = document.getElementsByClassName("variant_label")
for(var e = 0; e < labels.length; e++){
    // Update each label
    labels[e].innerHTML = labels[e].innerHTML.replace(/(?:^|[^!])(\[[^[\]]*])/g, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
}
```

**Example**

You can [see an updated example of your Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dr4vp2sq/2/) and demonstrated below :

[image]

Comment: The `for="radio_variant-id"` twice implies the use of duplicate ID.  Also instead of fiddling and jpg/giffing a code snippet might be quite [handy sometimes](http://i.stack.imgur.com/31qbV.jpg) :)

Comment: I really should get into the habit of that; Old habits die hard from spending years on forums that didn't support snippets :)